# React Context not updating when calling the function

Tags: reactjs

I Implement multiple language on my website, using different json file for translation.
I want to import different json based on user select.
I use context Api  to use Json file But
Initial context doesn't change when calling userLanguageChange function,

```
import {
  dictionaryList,
  languageOptions,
} from "../translations/LanguageSelector";
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const LanguageBisContext = createContext({
  userLanguage: "it",
  dictionary: dictionaryList.it,
});

export function LanguageBisProvider({ children }) {
  const defaultLanguage = window.localStorage.getItem("rcml-lang");
  const [dictionary, setDictionary] = useState(dictionaryList[defaultLanguage]);
  const [userLanguage, setUserLanguage] = useState(defaultLanguage);

  const provider = {
    userLanguage,
    dictionary: dictionaryList[userLanguage],
    userLanguageChange: (selected) => {
      console.log("questa è la lingua selezionata:" + selected);
      const newLanguage = languageOptions[selected] ? selected : "en";
      setUserLanguage(newLanguage);
      console.log(dictionaryList[newLanguage]);
      /*   window.localStorage.setItem("rcml-lang", newLanguage); */
    },
  };

  return (
    <LanguageBisContext.Provider value={provider}>
      {children}
    </LanguageBisContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

then I use this component to change language

```
export default function LanguageSelector() {
  const { userLanguage, userLanguageChange } = useContext(LanguageBisContext);
  console.log(userLanguage);

  // set selected language by calling context method
  const handleLanguageChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    userLanguageChange(e.target.value);
  };



  return (
    <select onChange={handleLanguageChange} value={userLanguage}>
      {Object.entries(languageOptions).map(([id, name]) => (
        <option key={id} value={id}>
          {name}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Comment: It should work from looking at your code. Please provide a CodeSandbox for me to get into detail here.
If you would like some feedback nevertheless I would advise you not to access localStorage on each render. You want to avoid expensive action like that. Instead lazily initialize your state like this:
```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => localStorage.getItem("rcml-lang"))
```
This will only access LS once, and you only need it once.

Comment: I also am not sure why this isn't working, but wanted to note that you have a state `dictionary` that is never used, and seems unnecessary.